# Most efficient way of creating a sprite component in vuejs using a sprite sheet

Tags: css, vue.js, sprite

I have a sprite sheet with 12x12 sprite, i am using background-position and requestAnimationFrame to create a animated sprite for my website.
Is there some improvements that i can do to create a better animated sprite component? Besides switching from bmp to png.
Thanks for your time.

```
<template>
  <div
    class="sprite"
    :style="{
      'background-position': `${this.animation[this.currentFrame].x *
        32}px ${this.animation[this.currentFrame].y * 32}px`
    }"
  ></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      start: undefined,
      animation: [
        { x: -7, y: 0 },
        { x: -11, y: 0 }
      ],
      currentFrame: 0,
      frames: 2,
      speed: 500
    }
  },
  methods: {
    steps(timestamp) {
      if (this.start === undefined) {
        this.start = timestamp
      }
      const elapsed = timestamp - this.start
      if (elapsed >= this.speed) {
        this.start = timestamp
        this.currentFrame++
        if (this.currentFrame >= this.frames) {
          this.currentFrame = 0
        }
      }

      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.steps)
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.steps)
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.sprite {
  background: url('http://localhost:8080/0-143-0-0.bmp');
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  align-self: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Your code looks very nice. It seems to be working. What is the problem? Just by reading the code I would say that dynamically processing the style attribute is not perfectly optimised, but I do not have an alternative to suggest.

Comment: As you can se here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp there is predefined classes, instead of generating a style attribute. This is maybe less dynamic, but its certainly more performant to maintain a css list with indexes on index on class names with your sprite sheet.

Comment: But it does not looks important. An important thing os how handy your way of working is.

Comment: i was just curious if there are other alternatives. thanks for the replies i will check the link.